# Create reusable angular matAutocomplete

Tags: angular

I would like to implement several identical autocomplete fields linked to the reactive form fields on one page. How to make a reusable autocomplete?

My code:

```
 <input formControlName="province"
                 type="text"
                 [matAutocomplete]="provinceA">
          <mat-autocomplete #provinceA="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn"
                            (optionSelected)="OnProvinceSelected($event.option.value)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptionsProvinces | async" [value]="option">
              {{option.name}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Have you gone through how ng-select was implemented?

Comment: I placed the code in the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create a component and implement the ControlValueAccessor interface.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-custom-form-control

After this, you'll can use it with a formControlname or ngModel, like this:

```
 <app-custom-component formControlName="formFieldName"></app-custom-component>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is this the only way to use autocomplete in FormArray?